# Unable to read postgres tables in pgadmin3

Tags: pgadmin

The following error occurred when I was trying to read a table using pgadmin3 in Ubuntu 14.04 and program crashed just after closing the dialogue box.

```
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/datetime.h(1733): assert "IsValid()" failed in GetValue(): invalid wxDateTime
```

Here's the back trace :

```
ASSERT INFO:
/usr/include/wx-3.0/wx/datetime.h(1733): assert "IsValid()" failed in GetValue(): invalid wxDateTime

BACKTRACE:
[1] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[2] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[3] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[4] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const
[5] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)
[6] wxEventHashTable::HandleEvent(wxEvent&, wxEvtHandler*)
[7] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)
[8] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventLocally(wxEvent&)
[9] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
[10] wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)
[11] wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)
[12] wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)
[13] wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
[14] wxTextEntryBase::SendTextUpdatedEvent(wxWindow*)
[15] g_closure_invoke
[16] g_signal_emit_valist
[17] g_signal_emit_by_name
[18] g_closure_invoke
[19] g_signal_emit_valist
[20] g_signal_emit
[21] g_object_notify
[22] g_closure_invoke
[23] g_signal_emit_valist
[24] g_signal_emit
[25] g_closure_invoke
[26] g_signal_emit_valist
[27] g_signal_emit_by_name
[28] wxTextEntry::WriteText(wxString const&)
[29] wxTextCtrl::WriteText(wxString const&)
[30] wxTextEntry::DoSetValue(wxString const&, int)
[31] wxTextCtrl::DoSetValue(wxString const&, int)
[32] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[33] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[34] wxListEvent::~wxListEvent()
[35] wxString wxString::Format<wxString>(wxFormatString const&, wxString)
[36] wxAppConsoleBase::CallEventHandler(wxEvtHandler*, wxEventFunctor&, wxEvent&) const
[37] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEventIfMatchesId(wxEventTableEntryBase const&, wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)
[38] wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable(wxEvent&)
[39] wxEvtHandler::TryHereOnly(wxEvent&)
[40] wxEvtHandler::DoTryChain(wxEvent&)
[41] wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent&)
[42] wxWindowBase::TryAfter(wxEvent&)
[43] wxEvtHandler::SafelyProcessEvent(wxEvent&)    
[44] wxToolBarBase::OnLeftClick(int, bool)
[45] g_signal_emit_valist
[46] g_signal_emit_by_name
[47] g_signal_emit_valist
[48] g_signal_emit
[49] g_closure_invoke
[50] g_signal_emit_valist
[51] g_signal_emit
[52] g_closure_invoke
[53] g_signal_emit_valist
[54] g_signal_emit
[55] gtk_propagate_event   
[56] gtk_main_do_event
[57] g_main_context_dispatch
[58] g_main_loop_run
[59] gtk_main
[60] wxGUIEventLoop::DoRun()
[61] wxEventLoopBase::Run()
[62] wxAppConsoleBase::MainLoop()
[63] wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**)
[64] __libc_start_main
```